# Average using grouping value in another vector (numpy / Python)

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to take the average of one vector based on grouping information in another vector. The two vectors are the same length. I've created a minimal example below based on averaging predictions for each user. How do I do that in NumPy?

```
       >>> pred
           [ 0.99  0.23  0.11  0.64  0.45  0.55 0.76  0.72  0.97 ] 
       >>> users
           ['User2' 'User3' 'User2' 'User3' 'User0' 'User1' 'User4' 'User4' 'User4']
```

Comment: Your two arrays are different lengths... Also are you looking for a solution in NumPy or (a much easier solution) in Pandas?

Comment: Sorry about that, they're now the same length. I'd prefer to stay in NumPy as I'm just learning Python and have decided to postpone Pandas for a little while.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A 'pure numpy' solution might use a combination of `np.unique` and `np.bincount`:

```
import numpy as np

pred = [0.99,  0.23,  0.11,  0.64,  0.45,  0.55, 0.76,  0.72,  0.97]
users = ['User2', 'User3', 'User2', 'User3', 'User0', 'User1', 'User4',
         'User4', 'User4']

# assign integer indices to each unique user name, and get the total
# number of occurrences for each name
unames, idx, counts = np.unique(users, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)

# now sum the values of pred corresponding to each index value
sum_pred = np.bincount(idx, weights=pred)

# finally, divide by the number of occurrences for each user name
mean_pred = sum_pred / counts

print(unames)
# ['User0' 'User1' 'User2' 'User3' 'User4']

print(mean_pred)
# [ 0.45        0.55        0.55        0.435       0.81666667]
```

If you have [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) installed, `DataFrame`s have [some very nice methods for grouping and summarizing data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name':users, 'pred':pred})

print(df.groupby('name').mean())
#            pred
# name           
# User0  0.450000
# User1  0.550000
# User2  0.550000
# User3  0.435000
# User4  0.816667
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by *"unique label for each user"* - in your example it seems that `User2` would have corresponding `label` values of both 0 and 1. Also, on SO you should post follow-up questions separately (you can include a link to the original question in order to provide context).

Comment: Okay, I'll do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to numpy, the simplest is to use [`np.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) and [`np.bincount`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html):

```
>>> pred = np.array([0.99, 0.23, 0.11, 0.64, 0.45, 0.55, 0.76, 0.72, 0.97])
>>> users = np.array(['User2', 'User3', 'User2', 'User3', 'User0', 'User1',
...                   'User4', 'User4', 'User4'])
>>> unq, idx, cnt = np.unique(users, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
>>> avg = np.bincount(idx, weights=pred) / cnt
>>> unq
array(['User0', 'User1', 'User2', 'User3', 'User4'],
      dtype='|S5')
>>> avg
array([ 0.45      ,  0.55      ,  0.55      ,  0.435     ,  0.81666667])
```

Answer (score 1):

A compact solution is to use [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) (disclaimed: I am its author), which implements a solution similar to the vectorized one proposed by Jaime; but with a cleaner interface and more tests:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
npi.group_by(users).mean(pred)
```