# Attach label information when averaging predictions across users

Tags: python, numpy

I have 3 datasets that contains predictions, usernames and labels, respectively. Using the code below I average the predictions across users (based on help from Jaime and ali_m from [Average using grouping value in another vector (numpy / Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29243982/average-using-grouping-value-in-another-vector-numpy-python)). The labels are associated with each observation and there's thus redundant information. I'd like to to find the unique label for each user using `idx`. How do I do that in NumPy?

```
>>> pred
   [ 0.99  0.23  0.11  0.64  0.45  0.55 0.76  0.72  0.97 ] 
>>> users
   ['User2' 'User3' 'User2' 'User3' 'User0' 'User1' 'User4' 'User4' 'User4']
>>> label
   [ 1  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0 ]

unq, idx, cnt    = np.unique(user_data, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True) # assign integer indices to each unique user name, and get the total number of occurrences for each name
predictions_user = np.bincount(idx, weights=pred) / cnt   # now sum the values of pred corresponding to each index value and divide to get the mean
```

Output is currently:

```
>>> unq
array(['User0', 'User1', 'User2', 'User3', 'User4'], dtype='|S5')
>>> predictions_user
array([ 0.45, 0.55, 0.55, 0.435, 0.81666667])
```

I'd like to add the last variable, named `label_user`. Each value would be the label associated with the user at the same index in `unq`.

**Sample output:**

```
>>> label_user
array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0])
```

Comment: Does that make it more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by passing `return_index=True` to `np.unique`. From [the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html):

> return_index : bool, optional
>
> If True, also return the indices of *ar* that result in the unique array.

This gives you the set of indices into `user_data` that give unique values in `unq`. To get the labels corresponding to each value in `unq`, you just use these indices to index into `labels`:

```
unq, idx, inv_idx, cnt = np.unique(user_data, return_index=True,
                                   return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)

print(unq)
# ['User0' 'User1' 'User2' 'User3' 'User4']

print(label_user[idx])
# [0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

I've renamed the array of 'inverse' indices to `inv_idx` in order to distinguish it from `idx`.

As with computing averages for each unique user name, there's also a simple way to get the corresponding labels using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'user_data':user_data, 'label_user':label_user})
print(df.groupby('user_data').label_user.unique())
# user_data
# User0        [0]
# User1        [1]
# User2        [1]
# User3        [0]
# User4        [0]
# Name: label_user, dtype: object
```

Comment: So `predictions_user` should now be calculated using `inv_idx` instead?

Comment: Yes. The way these two sets of indices work is that `user_data[idx]` gives you `unq`,  whereas `unq[inv_idx]` gives you back `user_data`. To compute `predictions_user` you want a 9-long set of indices, one for each element in `pred`.

Comment: It looks like the right solution, but it seems like you should print `label[idx]` instead of `label_user[idx]`, which has not been defined :)

Comment: I was still using the variable names from your previous question - they are now updated